# Alternating functions and differential forms

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms, calculus-of-variations

Can someone help me? Any sugestion will be helpful. According to Courant and John in Introduction to Calculus and Analysis, Vol. 2 chapter 5 section 5.1, if we take:

\begin{equation}
L = f(x,y)dy - g(x,y)dx
\end{equation}

the differential form of L will be:

\begin{equation}
dL = dfdy - dgdx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
dL = (f_xdx +f_ydy)dy - (g_xdx + g_ydy)dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
dL = f_xdxdy + f_ydydy - g_xdxdx - g_ydydx
\end{equation}

By **alternating differential forms** we know that $dxdy = -dydx$ and $ dxdx = dydy = 0$.

So, the answer will be:

\begin{equation}
dL = (f_x + g_y)dxdy
\end{equation}

I know that **alternating functions** have an important role in the calculus of determinants, as well in vectorial product. But, I do not understand the relation here, I tried to reach the answer performing a determinant, and the best I did was this:

\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix} f_xdx & dx \\ g_xdx & dy \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} f_ydy & dx \\ g_ydy & dy \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

But it makes no sense to me. So, why to use differential alternating form ? Why it is applicable in this situation ? This doubt has been tormenting me for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is related to the determinant is the operation $dxdy$ which should be written  as $dx\wedge dy$ and is defined as a bilinear map $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ by
$$dx\wedge dy\ (v,w)=dx(v)dy(w)-dx(w)dy(v),$$
$$\qquad =v^1w^2-v^2w^1.$$
This number is the area of the parallelogram spawned by the vectors $v,w$.

So, your $dL$ is proportional to $dx\wedge dy$, with the scalar $f_x+g_y$ as proportion.

Comment: I confess that I didn't understood what the wedge symbol means in your explanation. I usually see it as a logical conjunction, but, as you said about a paralelogram area, I think it is related to a cross product, am I right? 
You did a kind of change of variable, using w and v, so you have dx(v, w) and dy(v, w), so you calculated the area by v and w terms. Is it right?

Comment: The $dx\wedge dy$ is a more universal notation for a basic 2-form, which arise from the process of taking exterior derivative of a 1-form like your $L$. The $dx$ and $dy$ are only the exterior derivative of the "projector" functions $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ respectively. The 2-form $dx\wedge dy$ *eats* a couple of vectors $(v,w)$ to give the corresponding combination of projections to calculate the area generated by them.  Take into account that the book in your question is from 1965 with good stuff but at the math world of ideas and how to explain them had evolved a lot.